# Difference between executing script from terminal vs /etc/rc.local

Tags: boot, touchscreen, qt

I am booting my raspberry Pi to Terminal at the moment.

I have a script that I would like to run.
The script looks like this `run_gui.sh`:

```
python /home/pi/1.py &
/home/pi/Gui&
```

If I SSH into machine or if I just run `run.sh` from the terminal everything works fine. The program which is a full-screen `QML (QT)` application takes over the screen and then I can use the touch screen to navigate.

I would like to execute `run.sh` at startup, so I don't have to run it manually every time.

So I added have `/home/pi/run.sh` to `/etc/rc.local`
When I reboot the system now, I can see that the script is indeed executed since the user interface gets shown, but for some strange reason, there is a cursor visible on the screen, if I use the mouse and click around everything still works but the touch screen is not responding anymore.

Is there any difference between running a script from terminal/SSH or placing it in `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: Yes, `/etc/rc.local` is not executed as a regular user, and runs earlier (perhaps before touchscreen drivers have time to start).

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, so from where should I start the application?

Comment: For starters, try adding a delay to let your system more time to boot. Or you could boot to desktop and do what Jot suggested.

Comment: Do you use X11 or framebuffer? How about starting your app as a service? That's what I usually do with Qt applications I'd like to run all of the time. On a different system I could get rid of an unwanted cursor by `systemctl disable getty@ttyS0`

Answer (score 1):

To start a script or program in the desktop as a normal user (not as root), you can make a desktop file in the ~/.config/autostart folder: [Adafruit: adding vncserver autostart](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-7-remote-control-with-vnc/running-vncserver-at-startup)

Comment: Note that the OP boots his raspberry Pi to **Terminal**.

Comment: I am booting to terminal not x. your solution would not work.